# Removing boilerplate testing code with @Rule

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I'm writing tests right now and am realizing that they're all pretty similar in the beginning:

```
@Test
public void testThisMemoryOperation() {
    Assert.assertEquals("Sanity check failed, shouldn't be anything in memory yet.",
            0, memoryManager.getObjectsInMemory());
    /* ... */
}

@Test
public void testThatMemoryOperation() {
    Assert.assertEquals("Sanity check failed, shouldn't be anything in memory yet.",
            0, memoryManager.getObjectsInMemory());
    /* ... */
}

@Test
public void testTheOtherMemoryOperation() {
    Assert.assertEquals("Sanity check failed, shouldn't be anything in memory yet.",
            0, memoryManager.getObjectsInMemory());
    /* ... */
}
```

This seems needlessly repetitive. I could substitute this code with a simple method call at the beginning of each test to run the sanity check assert, but is there a native JUnit annotation like `@Rule` which I could use to simply run this test before running certain methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you have if the the [Verifier Rule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/Verifier.html), which adds a check after statement has been evaluated. It you take a look at the [source](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/Verifier.java) making a PreconditionRule would be very simple.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create a simple method and just call it? Something like:

```
private void test() {
    Assert.assertEquals("Sanity check failed, shouldn't be anything in memory yet.", 0, memoryManager.getObjectsInMemory());
}
```

Comment: You don't even have to call it in every test if you use @Before.

Comment: You shouldn't use @Before if it's a test.

Comment: It does not look like a test thou, but a validation that the environment is sane. @Before or a method would both seam appropriate to me. If it is used in many different tests then a Sanity Check rule might be appropriate but I think whiffs a little.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put this method in a base class and extend that class in your tests? It will get run automatically each time (at least with TestNG, but I suppose JUnit support inheritance as well).